# MeteorJs bootstrap load order packages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I am trying to apply a new set of CSS rules to my meteor app I am experiencing problems with the order of CSS loading. Bootstrap stylesheets loads after my custom stylesheet and override my CSS classes.

What I did:

I added bootstrap3 to my meteor app: $> meteor add bootstrap-3

and created an new package to customize the pacakges/css my-package
inside I have a packages.js descriptor:

```
Package.describe({summary: "fancy app theme"});

Package.on_use(function (api) {

  api.use(['bootstrap-3'], ['client']);

  api.add_files([
    'lib/client/css/stylesheet.css',
    ], ['client']);

});
```

What I am missing?

UPDATE:

I was wondering if the issue was because the code in my new package was inside a /lib folder and then got higher priority but I move out to a not /lib folder and still was getting more priority bootstrap package.

Cheers,
  Vicens

Comment: What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: I updated to the newest one 0.9